# Sequelize models - Setting associations when syncing in Node

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, pgadmin

I am trying to set my associations correctly so that they pick up the foreign key values when I make GET requests in Postman. For some reason when I try to sync them there is a new column created at the end in Pgadmin4 instead of matching to the primary column value at the start.

I know Sequelize is meant to pick out the correct fields to match up but It seems to always pick up the wrong ones for the tables that are being matched up. Is there a way I could be more specific when they are initialised in my server file? I have previously used PHPmyAdmin and not had any bother but this was without an ORM.

I know about eager loading from the Sequelize docs and this is what I have managed to put together from them. Do I always need to have the associations in my server file and the model? or can I have just one? I have built my tables, had my primary data uploaded by initialising values in the server file correctly however I could never get the foreign key fields to load and the include statements never returned in my requests.

**Is there a way for me to specify the column name on both tables so that the association is set-up correctly on the initial sync? At the minute I have a problem were there are columns being created with generated names of the joined up foreign keys names.**

**Should I be creating an index column in each of my tables that this extra column is created to match the other tables to?** I don't know how to auto increment each entry to match the primary key though (which doesn't allow foreign keys when I try to set them in pgAdmin).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it sorted. The best method for this is to number every "as" key with different numbers so when you are making a findAll include call you can identify the problem straight away. I may have done a bit extra from what I am supposed to but it produces the extra field data that relates to my foreign key values.

```
exports.adminUserList = (req, res) => {
    console.log("usegfu")
    users.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: diveLog, as: 'userID_FK1',
        }, {
            model: userRole, as: 'userRoleID_FK1',
        }, {
            model: article, as: 'userID_FK3',
        }, {
            model: posts, as: 'userID_FK7',
        }, {
            model: photos, as: 'userID_FK5',
        }],
    })
        .then((users) => {
```

server.js - association to match table models

```
diveLog.belongsTo(userLogin, { foreignKey: "userID", as: 'userID_FK', constraints: true, onDelete: 'cascade'});
userLogin.hasMany(diveLog, { foreignKey: "userID", as: 'userID_FK1',constraints: true, onDelete: 'cascade'});

article.belongsTo(userLogin, { foreignKey: "userID", as: 'userID_FK2',constraints: true, onDelete: 'cascade'});
userLogin.hasMany(article, { foreignKey: "userID", as: 'userID_FK3',constraints: true, onDelete: 'cascade'});

photos.belongsTo(userLogin, { foreignKey: "userID", as: 'userID_FK4',constraints: true, onDelete: 'cascade'})
userLogin.hasMany(photos, { foreignKey: "userID", as: 'userID_FK5',constraints: true, onDelete: 'cascade'});

posts.belongsTo(userLogin, { foreignKey: "userID", as: 'userID_FK6',constraints: true, onDelete: 'cascade'});
userLogin.hasMany(posts, { foreignKey: "userID", as: 'userID_FK7',constraints: true, onDelete: 'cascade'});
```